# Prevent from removing a node after drag drop in p-tree PrimeNG

Tags: primeng

I have a requirement, not to remove the node from the original PrimeNG p-tree  after dragging it. The default behavior is that a node that was dragged and dropped in another place is removed. Can i prevent that selected node from removal from parent tree.

Comment: why do you wanna drop duplicate values ?